# How does this responsive-iframe-container snippet work?

Tags: css

I don't recall how I've found [this code](http://themeloom.com/2013/02/tips-embed-google-maps-and-calendars-in-a-responsive-wordpress-theme/) and [applied it](http://answers.squarespace.com/questions/50460/how-to-embed-a-google-calendar-in-a-responsive-way) with **no issues** at all:

```
/* Responsive iFrame */

.responsive-iframe-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.responsive-iframe-container iframe,   
.vresponsive-iframe-container object,  
.vresponsive-iframe-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

It does some magical voodoo to make an embedded iframe google calendar become responsive, thus adjusting the iframe side according to your view size. It's awesome!

Question is: **how does it work?** `position` or `overflow` don't seen to do the trick. Nor all the other properties. I'd guess the trick's on that `vresponsive` thing, but I haven't added any jscript to deal with that, and I'm not even using that class. All I use is `responsive-iframe-container` as explained in the link!

It looks like it changes every element inside the iframe to adjust their size. It's quite crazy from my humble point of view. There must be a some magic movement fooling me there!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dcondrey/647fcdda17cd23715872

Comment: the older and very similar question is very different and offer different answers, from the little i could see. why is there such a need to close this one? either way, i can't care to get deeper into this today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, for whatever reason (often I find answers while asking questions, and delete the question), I just decided to google for **responsive iframe** and found [this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/27/making-embedded-content-work-in-responsive-design/) as the second result, which is probably where the code came from. It explains everything in detail and, basically, it is actually all together that makes it work and `vresponsive` has nothing to do with it.

Quoting from its summary:

> Embedded content has a habit of breaking responsive layouts, because it’s contained in an iframe with a fixed width. In this article, we’ve seen how to add a single containing wrapper, and some CSS, to ensure that all embedded content contained in an iframe resizes with the browser’s window.

And from the part it explains a bit about each detail there:

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

> This does a few things:
>
> - Setting the `position` to `relative` lets us use absolute positioning for the `iframe` itself, which we’ll get to shortly.
> - The `padding-bottom` value is calculated out of the aspect ratio of the video. In this case, the aspect ratio is 16:9, which means that the height will be 56.25% of the width. For a video with a 4:3 aspect ratio, we set `padding-bottom` to 75%.
> - The `padding-top` value is set to 30 pixels to allow space for the chrome — this is specific to YouTube videos.
> - The `height` is set to `0` because `padding-bottom` gives the element the height it needs. We do not set the width because it will automatically resize with the responsive element that contains this div.
> - Setting `overflow` to `hidden` ensures that any content protruding outside of this element will be hidden from view.
>
> **We also need to style the iframe itself**. Add the following to your style sheet:

```
.video-container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

> This targets `iframe`s inside containers with the `.video-container` class. Let’s work through the code:
>
> - Absolute positioning is used because the containing element has a height of `0`. If the iframe were positioned normally, we would have given it a height of `0` as well.
> - The `top` and `left` properties position the iframe correctly in the containing element.
> - The `width` and `height` properties ensure that the video takes up 100% of the space used by the containing element (which is actually set with padding).
>
> Having done this, the video will now resize with the screen’s width.